# reset button for a simple counter

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, counter

I'm making a pretty simple counter app for windows 7.1 in c# using visual studios 2010.

I've added two buttons, one + and one - (for adding or subtracting). The results are then being printed out into a textblock which all works fine.

Now I'm trying to add a reset button to put the value in the textblock back to zero and I'm struggling. I can make it come out as 0 with a Tostring but the counter value doesn't reset to zero!

I realise it's a really simple problem to fix but I'm coming up blank! Thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;


namespace PhoneApp1
{

public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    int counter = 0;

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void add_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        counter++;
        number.Text = counter.ToString();
    }

    private void subtract_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        counter--;
        number.Text = counter.ToString();
    }

    private void button1_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        //need to make clicking this button reset number(textblock) to 0
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void button1_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    counter = 0;
    number.Text = counter.ToString();        
}
```

You simply give the TextBox and the counter the number you want to set.

The reason why you cannot use [ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the `counter`-variable is, because counter is a [integer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/5kzh1b5w.aspx) and no [string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and `ToString()` returns a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void button1_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    counter = 0;
    number.Text = counter.ToString();
}
```